# Objective-c accessing values in plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm modifying someone elses code and struggling to access values within a plist, I can access Info.plist etc.. with code such as:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Info.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];

NSLog(@"ret=%@", plistData);
```

However when trying to access Account.plist, it returns null, I'm assuming it's a path issue?

Any help/pointers appreciated.

[image]

Comment: That's not how you locate files within the bundle.

Comment: But more pressing is that `InAppSettings.bundle` is not the main bundle is it...

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples of how to get either a Dictionary or an Array out of a plist.

```
//*******************************************
- (NSArray *)loadArrayFromPlist:(NSString *)plistName {
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: plistName ofType: @"plist"];
    return [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: plistPath];
}

//*******************************************
- (NSDictionary *)loadDictionaryFromPlist:(NSString *)plistName {
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: plistName ofType: @"plist"];
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: plistPath];
}
```